# How do I use the / (index) route twice for both logged in and logged out?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm working on a Laravel project. The project has a public (non authenticated section of the site) and an authenticated section (admin).

I am attempting to use the / route to display a public homepage view, and then when authenticated I'd like the same / route to display the admin authenticated view.

This is the attempted code:

**routes.php**

```
Route::auth();

Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('Public.home');
    });

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () { 

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('Authenticated.home');
    });
});
```

**Problem**
When I am logged out and try to access the / route, the Public controller (Public.home) is considered as an authenticated route (as placed under the 'auth' middleware in the route group above).

The middleware auth is set to redirect to / when any protected (authenticated) routes are accessed.

**Authenticate.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            }

            return redirect()->guest('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I am using Laravel 5.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to get around this.

The first would be to exclude your `('/')` route from the `auth` middleware and write your own to check if they are logged in or not and return the appropriate view based on that.

Something like this would do the trick:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        //The user is logged in
        return view('Authenticated.home');
    }

    else
    {
        //The user is not logged in
        return view('Public.home');
    }
}
```

Fore more info on writing your own middleware, see the docs for this.

Alternatively you can just create the one view `('home')` and then use and `if` statement to check if they are logged in or not.

Something like this would do the trick:

```
@if (Auth::check())
    //User is logged in
    //HTML that we want to show to authenticated user
@else
    //User is not logged in
    //HTML that we want to show to general public
@endif
```